# How to I change the Tab Signature?

Tags: error-handling

In VSCode, when you press tab, you get the

```
••••
```

symbol. I pressed a keybind, and now I see a

```
→
```

How do I revert to the 4 dots? Because I always get an indentation error and I need to manually press space 4 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the bottom right of vscode there should be a icon that says spaces:4 clicking this shows you the prompt to change between tabbed and using spaces instead